# Woocommerce 3.5: single product variation images show stretched 100x100 thumbnails after update

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, thumbnails

Can't figure this out after a lot of Google / stack overflow searches.

After a Woocommerce update to 3.5, the main image shown AFTER clicking on a variation is blurry because these are stretched from a cropped 100x100 thumbnail. This worked fine before!

Here you will see the problem: https://www.purewood.nl/kasten/kast-kalkverf-mat/

The gallery thumbnails work fine as you can see, it only happens when clicking on a variation.

I checked in the wordpress customizer, but can't see thumbnail sizes with 100x100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for me

It will fix the issue until the next Woocommerce update I guess

Visit [https://wordpress.org/support/topic/variation-products-images-issues-woocommrece/][1]

Comment: You're right, the new Woocommerce update (3.5.1) fixed it: 
* Fix - Don't default gallery variation images to gallery thumbnail size if flexslider is disabled. #21655

Thanx for your share.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue, right? http://prntscr.com/laaw07
have you checked by regenerate image? if not. then install WordPress Image regenerator plugin. and try once. Hope problem would be solved.

But still, if you are watching the same problem then contact me. I can solve it.
thank you

Comment: Thanx Abdullah, already tried regenerate thumbnails. Did not solve the problem tough.

Comment: No worries, if you need to solve it very soon. then you can use jquery code for removing this two attr. 

like this $('selector').removeAttr('width');

hope it will solve it. please try it

Comment: @Abdullah I'm facing the same issue as in the screenshot you provided. How did you solve this, can you help me? Regenerating thumbnails didn't work and removing the ing width and height attributes doesn't work either because the image url that is loaded is a 100x100 size thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust Thumbnail width (700 Worked For me, According To Your Size Lill Tweak)  & Keep Thumbnail Cropping 1:1

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the output of the json to replace the string that is being displayed.
-416x416 was the one that was bothering me
[image]

```
$variations_attr = function_exists( 'wc_esc_json' ) ? wc_esc_json( $variations_json ) : _wp_specialchars( $variations_json, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', true );
$variations_attr2 = str_replace("-416x416","",$variations_attr);
```